# OrderBy Linq expression in MVC5 asp.net View advice

Tags: c#, linq, razor, view, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently filtering a page that has courses and projects associated to those courses. I want to order those projects by which one received the most vote dollars -- attribute vote_amount. I am having trouble figuring out how to handle this through the controller and i can easily do it in the view however, I receive an error.

I have a loop inside of a loop and it is working quite well so far but i need to order.

```
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Courses)
    {
           <h2> item.CourseName <h2> 
           foreach (var project in item.Projects.OrderBy(project => project.vote_amount)
           { 
               <h2> project.Name <h2>
           }


     }
```

Seems to easy then i receive the following error.
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

I know i should keep this stuff in the controller when in using linq expressions but, I am having trouble get the desired order by array of projects i want inside another loop.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to order it before the foreach loop?

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.Courses)
{
    <h2> item.CourseName <h2>
    item.Projects = item.Projects.OrderBy(project => project.vote_amount).toList(); 

    foreach (var project in item.Projects)
    { 
         <h2> project.Name <h2>
    }
}
```

Comment: I still receive the error. Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type. Wish this was more flexible.

Comment: instead of `var item`, try to give item the class value of Courses list, for example: `foreach (CoursesModel item in ViewBag.Courses)`

Comment: Still no success. I currently have  foreach (Project project in ((List<SymposiumVoting.Models.Project>)@item.Projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.total_votes)))
                {

Comment: And still receive the error Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: I solved it. I made a method in my Course Class.         public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects()
        {
            return this.Projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.total_votes).ToList();
        }

Comment: Then called item.GetProjects()